Web3.js => _data.trim() is not a function?
Trying to deploy to ganache but keeps giving this error.
Error : 
TypeError: _data.trim is not a function
at ContractBuilder.deploy (C:\Users\user\Desktop\lotteryv2\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\lib\commonjs\contract.js:453:69)
at main (C:\Users\user\Desktop\lotteryv2\web3GanacheDeploy.js:15:36)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
const {Web3} = require("web3");
const {abi, bytecode} = require("./out/Contest.sol/Contest.json");
require("dotenv").config();

async function main() {
    const web3 = new Web3(
        new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545")
    );

    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
    (contract.options.data = bytecode), (contract.handleRevert = true);

    const deployedContract = contract.deploy({});
    deployedContract.send({
        from: accounts[0],
        value: 1e9,
    });
}

main().catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});


Please share the content of minimum reproducible version of Contest.json file from which you’re importing abi and bytecode.

nothing seems wrong compiled with forge

figured out thx for help and forge was compiling diffrently in bytecode there some other elements other than just bytecode. bytecode itself was under object element.

Great. Please add the revised code as an answer and accept it, so that it can be helpful for others who might face the same issue.

forge was compiling diffrently in bytecode there some other elements other than just bytecode. bytecode itself was under object element.
